# Integrate Angular Template With Spring Boot backend application

Tags: spring-boot, gruntjs

I am trying to integrate the [`SB Angular Admin`](http://startangular.com/product/sb-admin-angular-theme/) template to a spring boot application. For that, I added the [Frontend maven plugin](https://github.com/start-angular/sb-admin-angular/blob/master/README.md) to `pom.xml` in order to use `grunt task runner`.

When I clean install, everything works just fine, but when I run the application, all is some html text in blank pages (no design).
What should I do in order to integrate the template and run it alongside with the back-end on the same port on my localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example of web content management with Spring Boot and AngularJS integration in Spring Boot backend application :

- [Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)
- [Spring Security and Angular JS](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/)

Comment: Thank you but that is not what i looked for.
I just want to know how to run my angular template using grunt from the back-end side.

Comment: I don't get it. Since you want your whole application to run on the same port, it means your frontend has to be embedded in your spring boot application. So you have to package the whole application with Maven possibly Gradle. So what do you want to use Grunt for ?